# On some properties of convolution

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}.$ Can we find a function $g$ such that $f*g$ is well-defined, not identically zero and not supported on whole real line?

Note that if $f(x)=1$ then we can't find any such $g$.

($f*g$ denotes the convolution of $f,g$)

My try:[image]

Comment: We don't want $f*g$ to be analytic since then it cannot vanish on an interval without vanishing everywhere. But $f$ is analytic, so unless $g'$ grows so rapidly that the integral for $f'*g$ doesn't converge absolutely, $f*g$ will also be analytic. Thus $g'$ must grow very rapidly.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titchmarsh_convolution_theorem (OK, maybe it does not follow exactly from that theorem)